# Erro inicializando EvReflection Bool

Tags: swift

Tenho uma classe:

```
class Ingrediente: EVNetworkingObject 
{
    var idIngrediente:NSNumber!
    var nomeIngrediente:String!
    var adicional:Bool!
    var valorAdicional:NSNumber!
    var empresa:NSNumber!
}
```

e está classe recebe dados do `WebService`, porem estou com problemas para `serializar` os dados, apenas o campo adicional não esta `serializando`?

Os dados que chegam:

```
{"adicional":false,"empresa":500,"idIngrediente":508,"nomeIngrediente":"Ketchup"}
```

Faço assim para converter:

```
let ing = Ingrediente(json:json)
```

tenho mais 3 campos utilizando `bool` e estão com o mesmo problema, ***como posso resolver***?

Answer (score 2):

Eu não entendo nada de EvReflection, mas posso te ajudar a serializar o seu json usando API nativa Swift JSONSerialization para converter os dados json:

Primeiro voce deve se acostumar a usar sempre structs ao invés de classes se não estiver subclassing NSObject ou outra classe.

Não use IUO (implicitly unwrapped optional) se não for necessário e não adicione o nome da sua classe ou estrutura ao nome de suas propriedades. Sempre comece com let quando for declarar as suas propriedades. Resumindo, crie uma estrutura com um fallible initializer da seguinte forma:

```
struct Ingredient {
    let id: Int
    let nome: String
    let adicional: Bool
    let valorAdicional: Double
    let empresa: Int
    init?(json: Data) {
        guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: [])) as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
        self.id = json["idIngrediente"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.nome = json["nomeIngrediente"] as? String ?? ""
        self.adicional = json["adicional"] as? Bool ?? false
        self.valorAdicional = json["valorAdicional"] as? Double ?? 0
        self.empresa = json["empresa"] as? Int ?? 0
    }
}
```

---

Testando

```
let json = "{\"adicional\":false,\"empresa\":500,\"idIngrediente\":508,\"valorAdicional\":1.99,\"nomeIngrediente\":\"Ketchup\"}"
let data = Data(json.utf8)

if let ingredient = Ingredient(json: data) {
    print(ingredient.id)               // "508\n"
    print(ingredient.nome)             // "Ketchup\n"
    print(ingredient.adicional)        // "false\n"
    print(ingredient.valorAdicional)   // "1.99\n"
    print(ingredient.empresa)          // "500\n"
}
```

Comment: Opa Leo, obrigado pela resposta, eu tinha feito uma pergunta também no git do evreflection e é bem simples do que implementar tudo isto novamente. Mas caso venha a precisar já tenho seu exemplo. Muito Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

A solução passada pelo git foi de inicializar o Bool

```
class Ingrediente: EVNetworkingObject {
var idIngrediente:NSNumber!
var nomeIngrediente:String!
var adicional:Bool = false
var valorAdicional:NSNumber!
var empresa:NSNumber!}
```

desta forma ao serializar o objeto já altera o valor para o correto

Comment: faça o mesmo pro resto e retire a exclamação

Comment: recomendo que leia isso https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37 olha o ultimo paragrafo sobre reflection

Comment: Entendi, sou um pouco novo com swift, mas valeu a dica vou analisar bem. O interessante do reflection é que ele se assemelha ao Gson da google utilizado no android.